# Vue JS and Quasar: what is the @functionname in router-view?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm new to vue and quasar. I have this code in my vue but can't figure out what it is.

```
<router-view v-if="some_object" :abc="abc" :xyz="abc_xyz" :title="title" @updated="getABC" @refreshABC="getABC"/>
```

From my understanding router view allows you to dynamically insert other vue's content or something like that.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your VueRouter paths  will render the component you have putted in the path you are. you can have nested  if your VueRouter have childrens check vue router documentation it may be useful to understand
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view